Dynamic Tailwind CSS Classes Not Applying Correctly on Initial Render in React Component
I am trying to achieve a rolling y-axis list which I successfully coded. Here is the behaviour.

I'm working on a React component where I dynamically apply Tailwind CSS classes based on a prop (deviceWidth). The problem is that on the first render, the component does not apply the desired styles. However, if I hardcode the values and then switch back to the dynamic approach, the styles apply correctly.
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function Hero(props) {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(40);
  const myRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const element = myRef.current;
    let intervalId;

    const updateScroll = () => {
      if (currentIndex <= 160) {
        setCurrentIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex + 40);
        element.scroll({ top: currentIndex, behavior: 'smooth' });
      } else {
        setCurrentIndex(0);
        element.scroll({ top: currentIndex, behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
    };

    intervalId = setInterval(updateScroll, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [currentIndex]);

  const roles = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"];
  const sizing = {
    "sm" : {
        h: "2",
        t: "4"
    }, 
    "md" :{
        h: "4",
        t: "5"
    },
    "lg" :{
        h: "6",
        t: "6"
    }   
  };

  const deviceSizing = sizing[props.deviceWidth] || sizing.sm;

  return (
    <header className="mt-6 flex flex-col">
      <div className="text-center text-4xl font-semibold">I'm</div>
      <div className={`m-2 h-${deviceSizing.h} snap-y snap-mandatory overflow-y-hidden text-center text-${deviceSizing.t}xl font-semibold`} ref={myRef}>
        {roles.map(item => (
          <div key={item} className="mb-2 snap-center underline decoration-green-500">{item}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Hero;

Steps to Reproduce:

Create a React component that uses dynamic Tailwind CSS classes based on a prop.

Pass different values to the prop (deviceWidth) and observe the initial render.

Notice that the styles are not applied correctly on the first render.


What I've Tried:

Hardcoding the values instead of using the dynamic approach works.

Switching back to dynamic values after hardcoding seems to fix the issue temporarily.


Question: How can I ensure that Tailwind CSS applies the dynamic classes correctly on the initial render?
Additional Information:

I'm using Tailwind CSS with JIT mode enabled.

The issue occurs regardless of the value passed to deviceWidth (e.g., "sm", "md", "lg").


Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

As per the documentation:

The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.
If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
Don’t construct class names dynamically
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>

In the example above, the strings text-red-600 and text-green-600 do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
Always use complete class names
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>


You could:

Rework the dictionary to contain full Tailwind class names:
const sizing = {
  "sm" : {
      h: "h-2",
      t: "text-4xl"
  }, 
  "md" :{
      h: "h-4",
      t: "text-5xl"
  },
  "lg" :{
      h: "h-6",
      t: "text-6xl"
  }   
};

const deviceSizing = sizing[props.deviceWidth] || sizing.sm;

return (
  <header className="mt-6 flex flex-col">
    <div className="text-center text-4xl font-semibold">I'm</div>
      <div className={`m-2 ${deviceSizing.h} snap-y snap-mandatory overflow-y-hidden text-center ${deviceSizing.t} font-semibold`} ref={myRef}>


safelist the classes:
module.exports = {
  safelist: [
    { pattern: /^h-[246]$/ },
    { pattern: /^text-[4-6]xl$/ },
    // …
  ],
  // …
];



